# One of the reducer is not being triggered from effect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have tried as below to trigger the reducer from an effect. The issue is that the effect is not trigger the reducer 'OpenINFOWIdgetSuccess' while returning the action.

```
  @Effect()
  loadInfo$ = 
        this.actions.ofType(fromHeaderActions.EInfoActions.OPEN_INFO).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(
      this.store.select(fromSelectors.GetINFOPayload)),
    switchMap(([action, infoPayLoad]) => {
      let cAction: fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdget = 
          <fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdget>action;
      return this.infoService.loadINFO(infoPayLoad).pipe(
       // Dispatch success action
          map(response => new 
              fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdgetSuccess(response)),
      catchError(error => {
        return of(new 
         fromHeaderActions.OpenINFOWIdgetFail(error.message))
      })
     )
   })
 );
```

I have my action defined as below:

```
export class OpenINFOWIdget extends BaseGetDetailsAction implements Action {
  readonly type = EInfoActions.OPEN_INFO; 
  constructor() {
  super();   
 }
}

export class OpenINFOWIdgetSuccess extends BaseGetDetailsAction 
 implements Action {
 readonly type = EInfoHeaderActions.OPEN_INFO_SUCCESS;
 constructor(public payload: INFO) {
  super();
  }
 }

export class OpenINFOWIdget extends BaseGetDetailsAction implements Action {
  readonly type = EInfoActions.OPEN_INFO_FAIL;
  constructor(public payload: string) {
  super();    
 }
}
```

Create reducer as below after the comment:

```
case 
  fromInfoDetailsHeaderActions.EInfoHeaderActions.OPEN_INFO: {
      return {
        ...state,
        IsScreenOverlay: true,
        IsEditable: false
      }
    };
    case fromInfoDetailsHeaderActions.EInfoHeaderActions.OPEN_INFO_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        IsScreenOverlay: false,
        IsEditable: true
      }
    };
```

Once OPEN_INFO reducer is triggered from the effect. The value of IsScreenOverlay remains true all the time because effect is not triggering the OPEN_INFO_SUCCESS reducer. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try changing the ```switchMap``` to an ```exhaustMap```, it may be that the underlying ```Observables``` are causing the action to not get dispatched.

Comment: @AshwynHorton I do not see anywhere exhaustMap being used. SwitchMap suppose to work. I tried exhaustMap and gives error instead.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above issue not triggering reducer by updating return of the service to be  `return of(this.selectedInfo$)` instead of `return this.selectedInfo$;`

Original code prior to correction:

```
public INFOPayloadsource = new BehaviorSubject<INFO>(initINFO);
infoPayload$ = this.INFOPayloadsource.asObservable();

private SelectedInfoSource = new Subject<INFO>();
selectedInfo$ = this.SelectedInfoSource.asObservable();

  loadINFO(payload: INFO): Observable<INFO> {    
   if (payload != null) {
     this.IsInfoEnableSource.next(true);     
     this.InfoPayloadsource.next(payload);
   }
   return this.selectedInfo$;
  }
```